# php suhosin configuration

Tags: php, configuration, suhosin

Before I did any change to suhosin configuration,
the logging shows a lot of alerts,
including variable name length, value length, memory_limit, ASCIIZ null and so on.

So, what I do is to change related suhosin configuration setting.
i.e. increase value length, memory_limit, allow ASCIIZ null and so on.

After resetting, the alerts are reduced a lot.
However, it still have similar alerts sometimes, i.e. value length.

So, do I need to further increase these suhosin configuration settings?

Comment: Er, are you sure that your application actually required that those Suhosin protections be disabled, or did you just turn them off to make less stuff show up in your log? The correct response to an alarm going off is to address the issue causing it, not to disable the alarm.

Answer (score 1):

Suhosin in itself is a very outdated patch which was not really developed further since more than 4 years.
So i suggest, to dont use suhosin and use instead an current php version.

To your Question:
If you trust this code to dont misuse the things you allow it, you can/must increase further.
But as security issues because of the named things are very rare (i really never heard about one in the last 6 years, which would be solved throught suhosin. At all there was only one really serious issue inside of php) i suggest to follow the first i wrote.

Comment: last commit was in may 012: https://github.com/stefanesser/suhosin/commits/master and there is an 'initial' php 5.4 support, see on http://www.php-security.net/archives/8-Suhosin-0.9.34-dev-installation-howto.html anyway, meanwhile there is php 5.4.7 out and it doesn't look that suhosin will be updated in future